# Took over a project, flowplayer loads HUD but not video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a site that uses flowplayer to get around playing videos, but it's not working.

The console tells me there's specifically an issue with a line in my head that starts with video.addEventListener:

Saying: Cannot call method addEventListener.

I'm very new to coding if you can't tell.
site: sems-usa.com/Duramatic/index.html
I can post more context if needed. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 <!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0

  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();

    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)

    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}

}
//-->
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null
video.play();
},false);
</script>
```

More context

```
// a- tags with class "myPlayer" are transformed into video players

flowplayer("a.myPlayer", "video/flowplayer-3.2.6.swf", {



// this is the player configuration. You'll learn on upcoming demos.

plugins:  {

    controls:  {

        volume: false   

    }

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The line `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` says that your `var video = document.getElementById('video');` isn't actually finding an element on your page with the ID of video (video is assigned as `null`)

Try changing the line

```
<a class="myPlayer" href="video/Duramatic0713.flv">
```

to

```
<a id="video" class="myPlayer" href="video/Duramatic0713.flv">
```

Comment: Within my html? Doesn't look like there is. Should I find the element that contains this tag and change it's id?

Comment: Tried changing it, doesn't look like it's working. When I view my code from a browser, it shows me an <object> tag (which cant seem to see in my code) with the id = "video_api". Where it was previously "fp_8315223_api". So it had some sort of effect.

Comment: I tried putting in: getElementById('video_api') with no luck.

Comment: I am currently having issues with Flowplayer as well.. it can be tricky sometimes.  the `object` tag you saw means that the player is loading correctly now but something else may be wrong.  Are there any other errors? You might want to reference this page to see if everything looks correct in your code: [http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html)

Comment: Other than the console telling me that it can't     GET file:///F:/Duramatic/images/amongourcustomers.jpg  index%20problematic.html:31
GET file:///F:/Duramatic/images/qc.jpg That's the only error

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem you are working on now but `<span class="tagline" style="width="383"">` won't work the way you think it might.  CSS rules are separated by colons (and require a unit like px for pixels) like so: `<span class="tagline" style="width:383px">`

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say just this, but thanks for that.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that the video I'm trying to load is over 100 MB?

Comment: The size of the video would only affect how long it takes to load and not if it will load at all. I think more problems may lie in your website. The video player isn't even showing for me now. I will take another look at the code

Comment: I don't understand this: It seems to work in Chrome now, when the connection decides to not time out. The person who passed it off to me said it worked. Maybe I should just let the page load fully?

Comment: It's actually all loading for me just fine now in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  I'm still seeing that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` error but it's not effecting your player at this point.  It may be worth taking a look at the code in the future and cleaning up the few errors that are popping up.

Comment: Weird, why now? It was raining reeeally heavy here just a few moments ago. (No idea if that matters). But hey, if someone somewhere else on the planet can get this stuff to load, then I feel better. Do you think it's a server issue? Thank you for your time with this, I appreciate it.

Comment: I noticed earlier that your page was having a hard time loading so it may have simply not loaded the video due to whatever was causing that.  May have indeed been something with the server or connection of your server.   Hard to tell :/